# Calculating percentages in arbitrary number of columns

Tags: awk, bsd

Given this sample input:

> ```
> ID     Sample1     Sample2      Sample3
> One      10          0            5
> Two      3           6            8
> Three    3           4            7
> ```

I needed to produce this output using AWK:

> ```
> ID    Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
> One   62.50   0.00    25.00
> Two   18.75   60.00   40.00
> Three 18.75   40.00   35.00
> ```

This is how I solved it:

```
function percent(value, total) {
    return sprintf("%.2f", 100 * value / total)
}
{
    label[NR] = $1
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sum[i] += col[i][NR] = $i
    }
}
END {
    title = label[1]
    for (i = 2; i <= length(col) + 1; ++i) {
        title = title "\t" col[i][1]
    }
    print title
    for (j = 2; j <= NR; ++j) {
        line = label[j]
        for (i = 2; i <= length(col) + 1; ++i) {
            line = line "\t" percent(col[i][j], sum[i])
        }
        print line
    }
}
```

This works fine in GNU AWK (`awk` in Linux, `gawk` in BSD),
but not in BSD AWK, where I get this error:

> ```
> $ awk -f script.awk sample.txt
> awk: syntax error at source line 7 source file script.awk
>  context is
>           sum[i] += >>>  col[i][ <<<
> awk: illegal statement at source line 7 source file script.awk
> awk: illegal statement at source line 7 source file script.awk
> ```

It seems the problem is with the multidimensional arrays.
I'd like to make this script work in BSD AWK too,
so it's more portable.

Is there a way to change this to make it work in BSD AWK?

Comment: Simple answer - try nawk.  It should be part of the BSD install.  Some versions of awk are really old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the pseudo-2-dimensional form. Instead of

```
col[i][NR]
```

use

```
col[i,NR]
```

That is a 1-dimensional array, the key is the concatenated string: `i SUBSEP NR`

Answer (score 3):

[@glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)'s answer got me on the right path. It took a bit more work though:

- Using `col[i, NR]` made dealing with the column titles troublesome. It helped a lot to remove the buffering of the column titles and print them immediately after reading
- `length(col) + 1` was no longer usable in the final loop condition, as using `col[i, j]` made the loops infinite. As a workaround, I could replace `length(col) + 1` with simply `NF`

Here's the final implementation, which now works in both GNU and BSD version of AWK:

```
function percent(value, total) {
    return sprintf("%.2f", 100 * value / total)
}
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
NR == 1 { gsub(/ +/, OFS); print }
NR != 1 {
    label[NR] = $1
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sum[i] += col[i, NR] = $i
    }
}
END {
    for (j = 2; j <= NR; ++j) {
        line = label[j]
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
            line = line OFS percent(col[i, j], sum[i])
        }
        print line
    }
}
```